# SARIMA and ARIMA prediction fortecast wrong in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, forecasting, arima

I m trying to use SARIMA to predict future forecast values.
this is my data

```
2020-01-22 13:30:00 134.808840
2020-01-22 13:45:00 101.113338
2020-01-22 14:00:00 105.134895
2020-01-22 14:15:00 115.315380
```

I build a model, in this way

```
results = auto_arima(dataSugar['sugarValue'], seasonal=True, m=7, trace = True)
results.summary()
```

the summary gives this :

```
SARIMAX Results
Dep. Variable:  y   No. Observations:   1207
Model:  SARIMAX(0, 1, 3)x(2, 0, [1, 2], 7)  Log Likelihood  -3874.203
Date:   Fri, 06 Mar 2020    AIC 7766.407
Time:   21:57:14    BIC 7812.262
Sample: 0   HQIC    7783.676
- 1207      
Covariance Type:    opg     
coef    std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
intercept   0.0298  0.248   0.120   0.905   -0.457  0.516
ma.L1   -0.0624 0.024   -2.581  0.010   -0.110  -0.015
ma.L2   -0.3912 0.023   -17.259 0.000   -0.436  -0.347
ma.L3   -0.0769 0.027   -2.894  0.004   -0.129  -0.025
ar.S.L7 -1.0120 0.024   -42.474 0.000   -1.059  -0.965
ar.S.L14    -0.9861 0.022   -45.078 0.000   -1.029  -0.943
ma.S.L7 1.0219  0.029   34.793  0.000   0.964   1.079
ma.S.L14    0.9794  0.031   31.162  0.000   0.918   1.041
sigma2  35.9620 1.096   32.805  0.000   33.813  38.111
Ljung-Box (Q):  57.10   Jarque-Bera (JB):   231.80
Prob(Q):    0.04    Prob(JB):   0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H): 1.38    Skew:   -0.10
Prob(H) (two-sided):    0.00    Kurtosis:   5.14
```

So I applied :

```
model = SARIMAX(df['sugarValue'], order=(0, 1, 3), seasonal_order=(2, 0, 2, 7), enforce_invertibility=False).fit()
```

and the prediction on test and train set is very nice:

```
pred = model.predict(start, end)
```

[image]

So I thought that my model is correct (more or less)..in fact, I don't need strictly precision.

But when i try to forecast future values in this way

```
forecast = model.forecast(steps=96)
```

My output is

[image]

I think this is very bad. **Where I wrong?**
I checked the value and isn't the same, but are pretty similar.

```
    Prediction
2020-01-24 00:00:00 105.357804
2020-01-24 00:15:00 105.574045
2020-01-24 00:30:00 104.963241
2020-01-24 00:45:00 104.783142
2020-01-24 01:00:00 104.356709
```

Comment: Can you share your data?